# How can i compare the list<>of data which i have fetched from backend to Ui elements

Tags: java, list, selenium

How can i compare the list<>of data which i have fetched from backend into my java code  to the ui elements by fetching the data of entire div in selenium java ? Please suggest if there is a way i can fetch the text() of all elements from ui div and put into a list other than driver.findelements

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate by for loop and check with your text

```
following code for java , what I am doing here is open google browser and typing as "TESTING" AND store all results and checking word as "Testing Types" and click that option 


    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.util.List;

public class GooglesearchTests {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\User\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();





        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Testing");
        Thread.sleep(Long.parseLong("1000"));
        List<WebElement> LIST = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@role='listbox']//li/descendant::div[@class='sbl1']"));
        System.out.println(LIST.size());


        for (int i = 0; i < LIST.size(); i++)
        {
            //System.out.println(LIST.get(i).getText());
            if (LIST.get(i).getText().contains("testing types"))
            {
                LIST.get(i).click();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the question you are looking for the alternative to the `driver.findElements()`. You can use JavaScript Executor as below to achieve the same.

```
    List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    Long length = (Long) js.executeScript("return document.getElementsByClassName('r').length");
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
        lst.add((String) js.executeScript("return document.getElementsByClassName('r')[arguments[0]].innerText", i).toString().trim());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with Java stream API. Assume you have the page like this (say you have saved the code to `/tmp/texts.html`):

```xml
<html>
  <head/>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
      <div>text 1</div>
      <div>
        <div>text 2</div>
        <div>text 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

You now can do the following:

```java
public void testList() {
    driver.get("file:///tmp/texts.html");
    List<WebElement> webElements = driver
            .findElements(
                    By.xpath("//div[@id='root']//div[not(child::*)]"));
    List<String> texts = webElements
            .stream()
            .map(webElement -> webElement.getText())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(texts);
}
```

This example demonstrates how you collect texts from the elements with a single stream expression.

**P.S.** - this `[not(child::*)]` part of xpath means we're taking the leaf nodes only.